# how to configure web sphere portal 8 derby database in visualizer?

Tags: derby, websphere-portal, dbvisualizer

I want to view the data inside the portal Derby DB, what data it is storing, how it is retrieving, i want to visualize the derby databases of IBM WebSphere portal 8 Derby data bases in DBVisualizer. can any one tell be steps to configure in DB visualizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAH, i got it myself,

Give user id , and password as portal admin, and Database is : C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\PortalServer\derby\wpsdb
That is the location where portal derby data bases resides.

for more you can ref http://kotireddy143.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-configure-web-sphere-portal-8.html